# Correct way to load an interstitial Ad in Container View

Tags: swift, ios9, interstitial, uicontainerview

My initial view controller is a `UIView` which contains nothing but a `ContainerView`. I have embedded a `UIView` **A** in this container. When the user taps something in A, I segue to `UIView` **B**, and when user taps something in B, I segue to `UIView` **C**. 
**A** has a `NavigationController`, so when user is on **B** or **C**, user can tap the back button in the `NavigationBar` to go to the last view.

Each **A, B, C** have a `UIViewController` associated with it. In the `viewDidAppear()` of each of them I update a global static counter variable, and after a certain number of views I post a notification. In my initial view, I observe this notification and when posted I load my interstitial.

Since **A, B, C** are loaded inside my initial view container which is at the top always and which is where I load the interstitial, I expect the interstitial to show without any issues. But while navigating back and forth I still get the following warning intermittently (inconsistently):

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>    < MyApp.AViewController: 0x11d558a90 >

Upon searching, I found that this warning comes when you try and display a new viewcontroller before the current view controller is finished displaying. In my case I am doing the embedding through segues in the storyboard. I have no code where I am programmatically load views. So how do I fix this, or what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: This happens with custom container navigations. I struggled with something like this for months, got it working and then some innocuous change later, it began behaving oddly again. Post your various `moveToParentViewController` code so we can see what's going on. Try keeping a count with your static variables or other variables of how many times you toggle between B and C so see if there's an issue with creating too many B's or C's

Comment: I'd also suggest changing the title of your post - it's really about container view controllers not interstitial ads. Post your code too :-)